# How to display current bookmark in MercurialEclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

My team uses Mercurial bookmarks to denote branches of our project and not "long-term branches". However, the MercurialEclipse plugin does not show current bookmark in Navigator or Project Explorer. When I used Git and EGit plugin, I could always see what the current branch was. MercurialEclipse displays only something like "default 19 heads", which is not very helpful.
Is it possible to change the displayed information to be more precise? I have not found any related option in the configuration.